# how to remove listener on cleanup function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I remove the listener in this case when id is not defined? the cleanup is calling getMessages.off() but this is not defined.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
        const getMessages = database
            .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot)
            });
    }

    return () => {
        getMessages.off();
    };
}, [id]);
```

Comment: What is `database` in your code?

Comment: Really need to read up on how *block scoping* works in javascript and understand what a *block* is

Comment: You're assigning the function to a variable inside a block so it's not available in your cleanup's scope. I usually save listeners in mutable ref objects (useRef) which get updated by effects.

Comment: ok @charlietfl  reading now. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `getMessages` before if statement. This will be accessible in `closure function` for clean up.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let getMessages;
  if (id) {
    getMessages = database.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot);
    });
  }

  return () => {
    getMessages && getMessages.off();
  };
}, [id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend calling cleanups in effects with deps because this will lead to unexpected behavior, meaning it will get called earlier than expected.

You can save your cleanup in a ref, update it when id changes in another effect and call it in an effect with no deps.

```js
const getMessages = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    getMessages?.current?.off();
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (id) {
    getMessages.current = database
            .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot)
            });
  }
}, [id]);
```

Comment: I´m getting "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions" in the cleanup function

Comment: Turn `getMessages?.current?.off();` to `getMessages && getMessages.current && getMessages.current.off()`